# CRM 2011 Mail merge templates

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, mailmerge

I am creating a mail merge template in CRM 2011 and I need to pass a list of related entities to the entity that is being merged. For example, if I am merging records of an entity A which has a relationship to entity B, I wanted to know if there is a way to pass such a list of records of entity B related to the entity A into Microsoft Word 2010 through data fields on the mail merge template? Or is there some other way to handle this situation?

Also, a related question is, is there a way to pass an entity that is related by 2 levels to the entity being merged, for example, if the entity being merged is A, and that has a related entity B which in turn has a related entity C. Is there any way for me to pass the attributes of the entity C through the data fields on the mail merge template of entity A?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the out of the box mail merge you are not able to get all related data into your document. You are only able to get specific relationships, fields and you are limited in the levels of relationships.

You could take a look at www.mscrm-addons.com. The DocumentsCorePack gives you the possibility to get all related fields in you document. It doesn't matter if this is a 1:many or many to many or only a look up field. It doesn't matter if it is a custom field/relationship or a standard field/Relationship. With the AutoMerge product you even have the possibility to do this out of workflows and dialogs.

br,
Christian.

Comment: This add-on looks exactly like what I need. I am still trying to figure out how to get it to do what I want though. The standard template shows me only upto 2 levels of related entities and when I add the field and preview, it says the field does not exist in the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try yo use the same code found in the default "Quote for Customer" Template that Microsoft provides with CRM... it has some Field codes like this:

```
{ IF { MERGESEQ } = "1" "

....

{ IF { MERGEFIELD "LastItem } = "1" "

.....
" ""}
```